# JMeter: How do I inject specific range of values in 2 different parameters of http requests

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

We have a scenario where user has to enter numeric data in 2 fields. If user enters 1.11 in first field, he has to enter 1.20 in second field as it's the range he has to enter. Basically, whatever is the number entered in first field, next field should contain +0.11. That way we have 2 parameters in http request.

Comment: can you clarify your question ?showing more examples of possible combinations ?

Comment: Edited question, please check.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to generate pairs of random values where 2nd value should be larger than first one by 0.11 you can do this as follows (the examples assume [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)):

1. Create a random [Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) value using [RandomUtils.nextDouble()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomUtils.html#nextDouble-double-double-) function, truncate it to 2 decimal points and save it into `first` JMeter Variable

   ```
   ${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextDouble(1\,10).trunc(2),first)}
   ```

   here I limit the range to be from 1 to 10, however you may use different one
2. Add `0.11` to the `first` variable and truncate the result to 2 decimal points

   ```
   ${__groovy(((vars.get('first') as double) + 0.11).trunc(2),)}
   ```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Sum Doublees]

More information: [Mathematical Functions and Converting Data Types in Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mathematical-functions-and-converting-data-types-in-groovy)